# Cannot move out of dereference of `&mut`-pointer when calling Option::unwrap

Tags: rust

The following code doesn't compile:

```
struct Node {
    left: Option<Box<Node>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn new() -> Node {
        Node { left: None, right: None, }
    }
}

fn init_tree(root: &mut Box<Node>, n: int) {
    match n {
        0 => {},
        _ => {
            root.left   = Some(box Node::new());
            root.right  = Some(box Node::new());
            init_tree(&mut root.left.unwrap(), n - 1);
            init_tree(&mut root.left.unwrap(), n - 1);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut root: Box<Node> = box Node::new();
    init_tree(&mut root, 10);
}
```

The compiler error is

```
error: cannot move out of dereference of `&mut`-pointer
       init_tree(&mut root.left.unwrap(), n - 1);
                      ^~~~
```

How could I fix this error?

Comment: FYI, your code initializes `left` twice; I hope that's not surprising to you! ^_^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Rust compiler makes no pretence to intellectual eminence or scholarship sublime; it does exactly what you *tell* it to, not what you meant or wanted.

In this case, when you say `&mut root.left.unwrap()`, what you are *wanting* is something that takes `Option<Box<Node>>` by mutable reference and gives you a `&mut Box<Node>`; but that’s definitely not what you actually told it to do.

What you told it to do was to take a mutable reference to the result of `root.left.unwrap()`; let’s look at the signature for [`Option.unwrap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap):

```
fn unwrap(self) -> T
```

So what `root.left.unwrap()` does is it *consumes `root.left`*, producing in its stead a `Box<Node>` object (or panicking if it was `None`). You are then left with the entire expression `&mut root.left.unwrap()` producing `&mut Box<Node>`, *and consuming `root.left`* and hence partially `root`. Now this you are definitely not permitted to do, as it would leave `root` needing to be destroyed, but you only had a mutable reference to it—it is not yours to destroy. Hence the error.

The solution is not to use `unwrap` but rather to write a suitable `match` expression yourself. Remember, `.unwrap()` is just `match self { Some(x) => x, None => panic!(…) }`, there’s nothing magic about it.

You’ll end up with something like this:

```
fn init_tree(root: &mut Node, n: int) {
    if n != 0 {
        root.left = Some(box Node::new());
        root.right = Some(box Node::new());
        init_tree(match root.left { Some(box ref mut x) => x, None => unreachable!() }, n - 1);
        init_tree(match root.right { Some(box ref mut x) => x, None => unreachable!() }, n - 1);
    }
}
```

(The `box ref mut x` part is a bit of a tangle, I’m afraid; it produces a `&mut T` from a `Box<T>`, the `box` meaning “unbox the value” and the `ref mut` meaning “and then take a mutable reference to it”. Remember that everything is back to front in patterns, with `box` and `&` meaning the opposite to what they do outside and with the whole lot reading left to right rather than right to left. Also, while you could work with `&mut Box<Node>` I would recommend using `&mut Node` there which removes one level of indirection. Incidentally if you *were* still using `&mut Box<Node>`, `root.left.as_mut().unwrap()` would work as well.)

This can be improved by not stuffing the thing into `root` immediately:

```
fn init_tree(root: &mut Node, n: int) {
    if n != 0 {
        let mut left = box Node::new();
        let mut right = box Node::new();
        init_tree(&mut *left, n - 1);
        init_tree(&mut *right, n - 1);
        root.left = Some(left);
        root.right = Some(right);
    }
}
```

That is a lot simpler to look at, `&mut *left` being read right to left as “dereference `left` (which will get you a `Node` from a `Box<Node>`) and then take a mutable reference to it (which will get you a `&mut Node`).

Comment: The code above should be something like: let mut left = ...; let mut right = ...; Anyway your answer is great. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, I did indeed forget the `mut` there which is required if you wish to mutate the value. Amended, thanks!